# ID Increment in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am incrementing an `ID` in my app (add listbox to Grid). When I close the Windows app, my identity don't clean and stay this same. At the next run program `ID` starts from last value.

How can I clean the `ID` value after shutting down my program ? (I'm using Entity Framework).

In the example:

[image]

Identity in SQL Server is on true, because this value is ID and cannot be null.

How can I resolve it ?

Thanks a lot of :)

Comment: `truncate` the table... that should start from 1

Comment: Why do you want it to restart? How will you *identi*fy the records if you restart it?

Comment: I want restart becouse I checking adding tasks to ListBox and descibe to it for ID. Very slowly will be testing in 20 listbox, and after create that count of listbox I Can add task to this one. Deleting in SQL still do nothing and didn't restart ID value. I try check this one : truncate

Comment: I can't use `truncate` becouse I have reference on this ID

Comment: to reset the identity seed value you'll have to truncate the table, which means deletion of all entries (otherwise DBMS itself would run into Id issues). If you have FK's pointing to this table, this includes deletion of those rows as well.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I trying used `TRUNCATE` but this didn't reset FK's points and ID still is this same.